# Java PrivateKey differs from Android

Tags: java, android, private-key

I actually have a problem with encryption in Android. For testing I created a program which generates a signature using RSA and SHA.

```
public static byte[] generateKey(String privKeyModulus,  String privKeyD, String encryptCredentials)    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException,  UnsupportedEncodingException, SignatureException {

    byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privKeyModulus.getBytes());
    byte[] dBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privKeyD.getBytes());


    BigInteger modulusInt = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
    BigInteger dInt = new BigInteger(1, dBytes);

    RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivKey = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulusInt, dInt);
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    PrivateKey privKey = factory.generatePrivate(rsaPrivKey);


    // Here is the problem: 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(privKey.getEncoded()));

    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    sig.initSign(privKey);
    sig.update((encryptCredentials).getBytes("UTF-16LE"));          
    byte[] signature = sig.sign();

    return signature;
}
```

Now the problem is that I get different values as PrivateKey in Java and Android. That confuses me because the method is exactly the same in both programs and it is java.security which should work in both Java and Android. 
I also checked all of the other values (like the byte[] etc) but they are all the same.

Do you have any help?

Comment: Well, java.security just an interface to security provider, which is "SunJCE" in Oracle's Java and Android has it's own implementations, with "AndroidOpenSSL" being default.

Comment: Thanks divanov. That could be the problem. Do you know how to implement it in the OpenSSL way?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem. From the question it's very hard to say what is the problem as there are no key samples. Snippet seems to utilize java.util.Base64, which is not available on Android. And why don't you use some standard format to transport keys, like PKCS#8?

Comment: Just solved it by try and error. I just needed to add ', "BC"' (which is for BouncyCastle) in the getInstance("RSA") and it works.
I didn't use PKCS#8 because i first tried to do it the same way as in Java. And I am not so experienced with the differences between Java and Android. I will take a look at PKCS#8 and thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Encoding private key as PKCS#8 and Base64 to send it over and reconstruct private key:

```
@Test
public void testKeyConversion() throws GeneralSecurityException {

    /* Generate random key pair */
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    AlgorithmParameterSpec spec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(1024, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4);
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec, new SecureRandom());
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

    /* Encode private key as PKCS#8 base64 string */
    byte[] privKeyBytes = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();
    String privKeyStr = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(privKeyBytes);

    /* Decode private key as PKCS#8 base64 string */
    byte[] privKeyBytes2 = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(privKeyStr);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes2);
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privSpec);

    /* Ensure key is the same */
    byte[] privKeyBytes3 = privateKey.getEncoded();
    assertEquals(
            DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(privKeyBytes),
            DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(privKeyBytes3));
}
```

Use `android.util.Base64` instead of `java.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`, which is not available on Android platform.

Comment: Thank you for this example. I will try to understand and use this.